# console.log is not a function - error in javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am getting the error, `console.log` is not a function but this hasnt been an issue in the past. The error is happening in the first and second `console.log` and it doesnt get past there.

I have semi-colons so I am not sure exactly what the issue is?

```
document.getElementById("fileToRead").addEventListener("change",function(event) {
var input = document.getElementById("fileToRead");
//Variable for if statement to see if there is a header in the file.
var headerType = false;
console.log(input);
input = event.target.files[0];

console.log('test');

    for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
        var files = input.files[i];
            Papa.parse(files, {
            header:headerType,
            dynamictyping:true,
            complete:function(results){
                console.log(results);
                var input = results.data;
                if(headerType === false){
                    input.forEach(function(input){
                        jsonData.theData = theData;

                        var singleEntry = {
                            "symbol"    : input[0],
                            "date"      : input[1],
                            "open"      : input[2],
                            "high"      : input[3],
                            "low"       : input[4],
                            "close"     : input[5],
                            "volume"    : input[6]
                            };

                        jsonData.theData.push(singleEntry);
                        return jsonData;
                    }); // End forEach loop
                } else {

                } // End if statement for headerType
                document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData.theData);
                } // End Callback Complete

            }); // End PapaParse
     } // End for loop
});
```

I have even commented out the code so this is the end result and it still says that `console.log` is not a function!

```
// This is for the views/admin.ejs file only
//This file describes how the Admin page works, hiding divs and working with     the data
// importing


var jsonData = {};
var theData = [];

 document.getElementById("fileToRead").addEventListener("change",function(event) {
// var input = document.getElementById("fileToRead")
// //Variable for if statement to see if there is a header in the file.
// var headerType = false;

// input = event.target.files[0];

console.log('test');

    // for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
    //     var files = input.files[i];
    //         Papa.parse(files, {
    //         header:headerType,
    //         dynamictyping:true,
    //         complete:function(results){
    //             console.log(results);
    //             var input = results.data;
    //             if(headerType === false){
    //                 input.forEach(function(input){
    //                     jsonData.theData = theData;

    //                     var singleEntry = {
    //                         "symbol"    : input[0],
    //                         "date"      : input[1],
    //                         "open"      : input[2],
    //                         "high"      : input[3],
    //                         "low"       : input[4],
    //                         "close"     : input[5],
    //                         "volume"    : input[6]
    //                         };

    //                     jsonData.theData.push(singleEntry);
    //                     return jsonData;
    //                 }); // End forEach loop
    //             } else {

    //             } // End if statement for headerType
    //             document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData.theData);
    //             } // End Callback Complete

    //         }); // End PapaParse
    //  } // End for loop
 });
```

Comment: How are you running this code?  If in a browser, which browser/version?

Comment: Chrome 53.0.2785.143

Comment: is this block of code the one causing the error?

Comment: is this all the code? maybe somewhere else you have `console.log = nonExistFunction`

Comment: Listen to @BryanChen -- unless you're seeing this error in like IE6, somewhere, somehow, you are probably accidentally overwriting the console.log method with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have console redefined as a function further down the code! Complete newbie mistake...... hopefully I wont make this mistake again.